# How to delete pose created in new pose asset library blender 3

Tags: animation

How to delete pose created in new pose asset library blender 3 ?
Is there any python code snippet to do delete,read,create,update pose asset library operations ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the *Asset* mark from the action that defines the pose.

This can be done in the *Asset Browser* by selecting the pose and then choosing "*Clear Asset*" from the context menu. The pose will be discarded when the blend file is saved.

If you want to keep the pose in the blend file but don't want to mark it as an asset select the menu entry "*Cear Asset (Set Fake User)*".

[image: clear asset]

Alternatively, you can clear the *Asset* mark in the *Action Editor*. Select the action and click the *Asset* mark/"Shield" icon to toggle it.

[image: action editor mark asset]

For Python have a look at the API functions, e.g.  [`bpy.ops.asset.clear(set_fake_user=False)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.asset.html#bpy.ops.asset.clear)

 *Delete all asset metadata and turn the selected asset data-blocks back into normal data-blocks*