# Trying basic walk cycle. Poses not applying properly from pose library

Tags: animation, rigify, pose-mode, asset-browser

I am attempting a basic walk cycle for a model I have rigged with Rigify. I am struggling with several things.

Firstly, when I try to apply poses I have saved, they all appear to apply as the same pose - a contact pose. This happens even though in the thumbnail, they are clearly different poses. I have selected all the relevant bones when creating the pose assets.

Secondly, when I hit "create pose asset" from within the Dope sheet, all my previous keyframes disappear, leaving only new ones on the keyframe I've created the asset on.

Lastly, I can't find any way to delete pose assets I've made. Pose library getting clogged as a result.

Any help hugely appreciated. I will add my blend file to this query.
The poses I'm struggling with are all of those labelled as "Walk v2".

[image: Screenshot of pose]

Comment: Is there a blend file added to this question? -- Have you created the poses first and do you want now to create a walk cycle from it? Or do you try to create the poses while you create the walk cycle? -- Just a few notes: the pose library only supports single poses for now. In the future, it is planned that you can create short animation strips. For each pose, an action with 1 frame is created. The frame has the keyframes for the selected bones. To create and to apply the pose the bones must be selected. The camera & the Workbench engine is used to create the preview image.

Comment: Related question: [How to delete pose created in new pose asset library blender 3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/270903/107598)